# Short story where a reptilian alien named Michael is revealed when burned at the stake (might be titled Michael)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short science fiction story about an alien named Michael who goes to a village but ends up being burned at the stake, which reveals his reptilian body. He befriends a girl and her brother from the village and she kisses him and is banished to live in the wilds of the forest.

Comment: Probably not Francesca Marques's story.

Comment: Not certain on Christopher Woodforde... haven't found a review of it yet, but the only referenced book is ghost fiction.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: [One of these stories](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=michael&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=SHORTFICTION&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) ?